# Solve for roots of equation that includes dependent/independent variables in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to solve for `Y(x):`

```
Y(x) = A - B*x + C*ln(A/Y(x))

where A, B, and C are defined
```

I have no clue how to go about this, in either `Python or mathematically`.  I want to try finding the roots using fsolve or something, but I don't think I can treat `x and Y(x)` as independent of each other.

Please help.

Comment: Looks like more of a Mathematical problem. You may try seeking help at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Tip: figure out the mathematics first. _Then_ worry about expressing it in code.

Answer (score 0):

Equation like that are not simple equation that can be solved in analytical way(in fact only a small group of euqation in well-defined form can be solved to a accurate solution), so this should be solved numerically to get an approximate solution.